# How to use a jar file in conjunction with another in Java from the command prompt

Tags: java, command-line

I am doing an assignment for class and I was given a jar file for the Display board and I have to code some basic functions for it in a separate Java file. Now, I need the Display to be called in the program I'm writing, and so I used:

(I'm using a window PC)

`javac -cp lab1.jar;.Wrapping.java`

However, every time I try this, it gives me this error:

```
javac: no source files
usage: javac <options><source files>
use -help...
```

Now, I've changed my directory to the proper folder and the file is in there, and still, I cannot get it to run. What am I doing wrong? I can get other programs to compile and run from the command prompt, it is just this one that I cannot. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If your command it posted as you ran it literally, without the space between . and Wrapping.java, you need a space there.

Answer (score 1):

*Try this command to compile:*

```
set classpath=lab1.jar
javac Wrapping.java
```

**OR**

```
javac -cp lab1.jar Wrapping.java
```

*Try this command to execute:*

```
set classpath=lab1.jar;.
java Wrapping ::Make sure its class name with main()
```

**OR**

```
java -cp lab1.jar;. Wrapping
```